# Assign Names to Phone Numbers using text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assign all names to a phone number. Nothing much else to explain. I think there are a lot of improvements that can be done with this code. Not really sure what though.

[here](https://pastebin.com/TvnnJNT0) is the Name/Phone Number List

```
phone = open("Phone.txt", "r");

name_list = []
phone_list = []

append_data = "name"

iterate_first = True
for data in phone.readlines():
    if (data == '\n'):
        append_data = "phone"

    if (append_data == "name"):
        name_list.append(data.strip())
    else:
        if (iterate_first == False):
            phone_list.append(data.strip())
        else:
            iterate_first = False

for data in name_list:
    name_index = name_list.index(data)
    print("%s is associated with the phone number %s" % (data, phone_list[name_index]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `with` when opening files. It automatically closes the file, which you didn't do. And allows readers to easily know the scope of the file.
- You can loop through a file, so you don't need to use `readlines`.
- Rather than using `iterate_first` you can use `continue`. This is as you skip the line which is empty. It also makes your code simpler, as it explicitly says what that variable does.
- Rather than using `name_list.index(data)`, you could instead use `enumerate`, or even better, `zip`.
- Rather than using `%s` formatting, you can use `str.format`. This has a simpler interface, and is the same style as f-strings, which are the new best way to format strings. However f-strings are Python 3.6+.
- Your names are mostly good, `name_list`, but using plurals may be better, `names`.

Using all the above can allow you to get:

```
with open("Phone.txt", "r") as phone:
    names = []
    numbers = []
    append_data = "name"
    for data in phone:
        data = data.strip()
        if (data == ''):
            append_data = "phone"
            continue

        if (append_data == "name"):
            names.append(data)
        else:
            numbers.append(data)

for name, number in zip(names, numbers):
    print("{} is associated with the phone number {}".format(name, number))
```

The above is good, however, I'd personally use `itertools.takewhile`, and a function. You may find the code harder to read, however I don't so you may not want to use the following.
And so I'd write:

```
from itertools import takewhile


def read_phone_file(phone_file):
    with open(phone_file, "r") as f:
        lines = (item.strip() for item in f)
        return list(takewhile(bool, lines)), list(lines)


names, numbers = read_phone_file("Phone.txt")
for name, number in zip(names, numbers):
    print("{} is associated with the phone number {}".format(name, number))
```